# Como imprimir mais de um número máximo de uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Pessoal o exercício da minha faculdade é o seguinte:
Escrever um programa que receba os nomes de 5 estudantes e coloque em uma lista e suas respectivas notas em outra lista.

O exercício pede para imprimir a nota do maior aluno (O que eu já consegui fazer), porém não estou conseguindo imprimir o nome de mais de um aluno (Em caso de empate de nota máxima), até agora meu código está dessa forma:

```
aluno = []
nota = []


while len(aluno) < 5:
    aluno.append(input('Digite o nome do aluno'))
    nota.append(int(input('Digite a média final do aluno')))

print(f'O aluno com maior nota foi o {aluno[nota.index(max(nota,key=int))]}')
```

Answer (score 4):

Apesar das outras respostas funcionarem, tem um detalhe que eu gostaria de comentar a respeito.

Elas estão chamando [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) várias vezes, sem necessidade. Para entender melhor, vamos modificar só um pouco o programa:

```
def maior(notas):
    print('procurando maior nota')
    return max(notas)

aluno = ["alice", "bob", "carol", "dave", "eve"]
notas = [10, 7, 9, 10, 10]
maiores_notas = [aluno[i] for i in range(len(aluno)) if notas[i] == maior(notas)]
```

Ou seja, criei outra função que chama `max` mas também imprime uma mensagem. A saída é:

```
procurando maior nota
procurando maior nota
procurando maior nota
procurando maior nota
procurando maior nota
```

A função foi chamada 5 vezes (uma para cada nota). Mas isso é redundante e desnecessário, pois a lista de notas não vai ser mais modificada e portanto eu só preciso procurar uma vez. O problema aqui é que `max` percorre todos os elementos da lista para encontrar o maior, e quando você percorre várias vezes a mesma lista sem necessidade, está criando uma variação do chamado [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) (que é um sinônimo jocoso para um algoritmo "burro").

---

Enfim, uma solução melhor é obter o maior apenas uma vez, e depois verificar os alunos que têm esta nota.

E como já sugerido em outra resposta, você pode usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para percorrer ambas as listas ao mesmo tempo:

```
alunos = [] 
notas = []
for _ in range(5): 
    alunos.append(input('Digite o nome do aluno: ')) 
    notas.append(int(input('Digite a média final do aluno: ')))

maior_nota = max(notas) # agora eu só chamo max uma única vez
maiores_notas = [ aluno for aluno, nota in zip(alunos, notas) if nota == maior_nota ]
```

Usei um `range` para repetir 5 vezes a leitura dos dados (e usei a variável `_` no `for`, que é uma convenção do Python para indicar que a variável não é usada no *loop* - eu apenas quero repetir algo 5 vezes, mas não vou usar a variável na iteração).

Também mudei o nome das listas para `alunos` e `notas` (ambos no plural), já que elas vão guardar respectivamente vários alunos e notas. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

---

É claro que para listas pequenas a diferença será insignificante, e se for só um exercício, talvez isso não passe de micro-otimização. Mas rode várias vezes para listas maiores e começará a fazer uma diferença considerável. Lembre-se que [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/).

Fazendo um teste com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), podemos ver a diferença:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import choices

chamar_uma_vez = "maior_nota = max(notas)\nmaiores_notas = [ aluno for aluno, nota in zip(alunos, notas) if nota == maior_nota ]"
chamar_varias_vezes = "maiores_notas = [ aluno for aluno, nota in zip(alunos, notas) if nota == max(notas) ]"

qtd = 1000
alunos = list(range(qtd)) # cria uma lista com 1000 elementos
notas = choices(range(11), k=qtd) # cria uma lista com 1000 notas aleatórias entre 0 e 10

execucoes = 1000 # executar mil vezes cada um
# imprime o tempo em segundos para cada um dos algoritmos
print(timeit(stmt=chamar_uma_vez, number=execucoes, globals=globals()))
print(timeit(stmt=chamar_varias_vezes, number=execucoes, globals=globals()))
```

Primeiro, vale lembrar que os tempos podem variar de uma máquina para outra, pois depende de vários fatores, como o *hardware*, se havia outras coisas rodando na máquina, etc.

Mas enfim, criando listas com 1000 alunos e 1000 notas, e executando 1000 vezes cada busca, na minha máquina eu obtive 0,07 segundos na primeira solução (chamando `max` apenas uma vez) e 21 segundos na segunda solução (chamando `max` várias vezes). Ou seja, quase 300 vezes mais lento. Rodei várias vezes e os resultados não variavam muito além disso.

[No Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/ViciousAuthorizedConversion#main.py) os tempos foram diferentes (por volta de 0,3 a 0,4 segundos para a primeira solução e por volta de 80 segundos na segunda), mas mesmo assim vemos que chamar `max` várias vezes foi cerca de 200 vezes mais lento.

Usando listas com 10 notas, a diferença já não é tão grande assim (0.001 contra 0.005), mas como eu já disse, para listas pequenas a diferença é imperceptível. Mas é aí que mora o perigo: você vê que "funciona" e só vai perceber que tem problema lá na frente. Apesar de ser "somente um exercício", é importante se atentar a esses detalhes desde já, para não achar que qualquer código que "funciona" é necessariamente um código bom.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso eh a seguinte:

```
aluno = ["alice", "bob", "carol", "dave", "eve"]
notas = [10, 7, 9, 10, 10]

maiores_notas = [aluno[i] for i in range(len(aluno)) if notas[i] == max(notas)]
```

Dessa forma, tu iteras sobre a lista `aluno` filtrando apenas os alunos que tenham nota igual a maior nota presente na lista `notas`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar list comprehension e utilizar a função zip:

```
aluno = [] 
nota = []

while len(aluno) < 5: 
    aluno.append(input('Digite o nome do aluno: ')) 
    nota.append(int(input('Digite a média final do aluno: ')))
```

Neste trecho é que verificamos as maiores notas:

```py
maiores_notas = [a for a, n in zip(aluno, nota) if n == max(nota) ]
```

Imprimindo:

```py
print(f'\nO(s) aluno(s) com maior(es) nota(s): {", ".join(maiores_notas)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar um algoritmo que seja capaz de capturar o **nome de 5** alunos, armazenando-os dentro de uma lista e capturar as **notas** destes 5 alunos, armazenando-as dentro de outra lista. Em seguida, o código seja capaz de identificar a **maior** nota e dizer quais alunos obtiveram a maior nota.

Pois bem, a lógica deste código será a seguinte:

1. Capturar e armazenar o nome dos 5 alunos em uma lista;
2. Capturar e armazenar as notas destes 5 alunos em outra lista;
3. Calcular a maior nota;
4. Identificar o(s) aluno(s) que obtive(ram) a maior nota.

**Observação**

Como as notas dos alunos podem vir na forma...

```
7, 7.5, 8, 9.5
```

..achei por bem utilizar o tipo **float** e não o tipo **int**.

Uma das formas corretas para se implementar este código é:

```
nomes = list()
notas = list()
for i in range(1, 6):
    nomes.append(input(f'Digite o nome da {i}ª pessoa: ').capitalize())
    notas.append(float(input(f'Digite a nota de {nomes[i - 1]}: ')))

maior_nota = max(notas)

print(f'A maior nota foi {maior_nota}, sendo a mesma obtida pelo(s) aluno(s):')
for j, k in zip(nomes, notas):
    if k == maior_nota:
        print(j)
```

Observe que o **primeiro bloco for** monta as duas listas - nomes e notas. Depois disso é calculado a maior nota. Em seguida, o **segundo bloco for** - com ajuda da função zip() - percorre as duas listas de forma simultânea, verificando as ocorrências da maior nota e, para cada ocorrência da maior nota é impresso o nome da pessoa que a obteve.

Ao final da execução deste código, teremos o nome de cada pessoa que obteve a maior nota.